# How to share an Intellij Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have created an IntelliJ plugin, but I want to share it with someone. I don't want to publish it on JetBrains plugin repository because this plugin is for trivial functionality and academic use only.

Is there a way to share the plugin? For Example like we share an Android (sharing APK file) app. So that I don't have to share the entire code?

Comment: You can share the plugin zip. Others can install the plugin from disk by specifying the location of this file.

Comment: You mean code as a Zip file? And people can directly install it, without needing to compile or run the project?

Comment: No, export the plug-in in the IDE, it will produce the compiled version zip.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `Build | Prepare plugin for Deployment` in your plugin project.

This will create a zip or a jar under your project root, which is exactly what you want.
Ask your friends to install it via `Settings | Plugins | Install plugin from disk`, and select the jar (or the zip), click `OK`, reboot IntelliJ IDEA, and your plugin will work.

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin doesn't include **`Gradle`**

- Make your project by invoking **Build | Build Project or Build | Build Module** .
- Generate `ZIP` or `JAR` file. In the main menu, select **Build | Prepare Plugin Module  for Deployment.**

Now you will find a `.zip` or `.jar` file under your root directory. You can send this file to your friends.

> If the plugin module does not depend on any libraries, a `.jar` archive
>   will be created. Otherwise, a `.zip` archive will be created including
>   all the plugin libraries specified in the project settings.

Note: To learn more about publishing the IntelliJ plugins read [IntelliJ documentation (Deploying a Plugin)](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/deploying_plugin.html).